# In privileges, it mentions reduction of advertisements. What advertisements is it talking about?

Tags: support, privileges, advertising

I noticed that at 200 rep, [advertisements are reduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).  I have never seen an ad on here to my knowledge, so what is it talking about?

Comment: If you are not seeing advertisements, *switch of your ad blocker*.

Comment: Oh, I see rofl!  Normally I find my ad-blocker, though helpful, is usually not 100% effective.  First time it blocked all ads on a site.

Comment: In conclusion, this is a result of me not realizing my adblocker was doing its job lol.

Comment: A unicorn weeps, in Iceland. I just want you to know that.

Comment: Everyone should run ad blockers at all times, because it is the single most effective way to improve *security* for the average user; even the big, reputable ad networks that ought to be able to weed out the malware have repeatedly missed it.  I wouldn't be surprised if ad-blocking was more effective than virus scanners these days.  Yes, that means the entire Internets need to switch to non-ad-based business models.  That's the way the cookie crumbles.

Comment: Careers 2.0 ads don't count as ads in my head.

Comment: @Zack Ad blockers are even more necessary when the ads in question track you based on a number of parameters despite you not wanting it to happen (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237062/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-policy-on-honoring-do-not-track-browser-s).

Comment: @Zack, please suggest one :)

Comment: @Jason Adblock+ with Pop-up blocker addition and Ghostery are two VERY great anti-ad/anti-tracking add-ons.

Comment: I tend to use AdBlock+ with Privacy Badger instead of Ghostery. I don’t know, Ghostery leaves an uncomfortable feeling, considering that it’s made by a player in the ad industry.

Comment: @TylerH & Jonas - I meant suggest a non-ad-based business model that will be successful for web sites.  Many have tried and failed.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are three advertisement slots on a given page, *provided you don't have an ad-blocker installed*.

There is one leaderboard-style advertisement below the question title:

> [image: title slot]

One or two advertisements in the side bar above the post links list:

> [image: side bar slot]

and another leaderboard between the answers:

> [image: between answers slot]

Once you reach the [reduced ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) the title and between-answers leaderboard advertisements are no longer shown. You can [re-enable them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not/275687#275687) if you really want to, to support Stack Overflow.

Comment: I had not considered the elements on the right as ads. Thats good, cause I hate ads but I don't feel bothered by them.

Comment: But there are other tiny ads that show up and track you without any regards for your browser settings.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237062/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-policy-on-honoring-do-not-track-browser-s for more.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer If you had advertisements, you should consider why that is. Every company that you have worked for advertises. Any communication can be useful or deceptive.

Comment: @canon: it does; there is a campaign for a London dev conference running lately (advertising that Jon Skeet is speaking there) and I've also seen AirPair.com ads (mostly because some of those featured me).

Comment: @EricWilson No. Companies I work for usually don't advertise. When I buy stuff I take the annoyance of their ads into consideration. When they bother me to much, I don't buy from them. Decent ads (like here) are fine though.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I'm curious how your company finds new customers -- any sales communication is an advertisement.

Comment: @EricWilson No. Having a booth at a conference is not an ad. Word of mouth is not an ad. Appearing in Search Engines is not an ad. There are lots of ways of sales communication that is not an ad. (Except you define ad as "Any sales communication" - but then we have to talk about our differing versions of English)