# Re-enable adverts?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, advertising

Strange question I know, but occasionally I connect to Stack Overflow without logging in, and I see the adverts, and (gosh) some of them are actually quite interesting! Is there any way I can choose whether to see them or not while I'm logged in?

Some thoughts on the feature:

When the user gets to 200, an announcement of some sort appears, congratulates him/her, and explains that he/she can now turn off some or all of the adverts if required. Maybe the announcement could explain further that, by allowing some adverts, the user is helping to support Stack Overflow. It could be further be explained that the ads are development-related and region-specific (in some cases).

Importantly, the user should be able to turn on or off the feature at any time, so he/she feels in control.

Comment: This would make a good feature request I think. The ability to show ads anyway and support SE.

Comment: Sounds good - is there an official place for feature requests?

Comment: Right here :) use [meta-tag:feature-request] instead of [meta-tag:discussion] in the tags. Perhaps you could just edit your current post and make it a feature request, check with @Martijn by commenting on his answer if that's OK with him.

Comment: You are a wonderful person and you should feel happy.

Comment: It might be kind of ambiguous what upvotes mean on this post. I'll upvote it in a sense that I'm completely for people having an opt-in to see all the ads in the world. But I would most definitely **not** enable it myself.

Comment: you can give me all your rep in bounty to go below 200 rep. congratulations :)

Comment: When are they gonna enable it?

Comment: Update: [Choose to see reduced ads or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275687)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update**: As of February 2016, you can now [re-enable the extra advertisements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not/275687#275687).

---

No, after reaching 200 points and earning the [*Reduce Ads* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) the two leaderboard ads are no longer shown, and 
you cannot re-enable them. That'd have to be an entirely new preference.

You do still get to enjoy the advertisements in the sidebar though. Also see [In privileges, it mentions reduction of advertisements. What advertisements is it talking about?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267232/in-privileges-it-mentions-reduction-of-advertisements-what-advertisements-is-i)

The Stack Exchange team has been very careful not to clutter the preferences with new options; there is reason behind the sparseness of the preferences panel. However, if people really want to keep the two leaderboard ads and help generate additional revenue, then I can see that such an option could be added by the team. It'd depend on how many people would actually enable this for this to have business value.

I *would* prefer it if the option was disabled by default; e.g. when you hit 200 points ads go unless you explicitly enabled them again. The privilege documentation would have to be updated to reflect that you now have a *choice* and you can opt-in.

You already discovered one work-around: log out or use a [privacy mode window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode). Another would be to reduce your reputation to below 200, by setting a few big bounties, for example.

Comment: Ok, seems a shame though as one of the banners was for a software architecture conference near me, that actually looked quite good.

Comment: Lol - reduce my reputation - really struggled to get this far...!

Comment: @Surfbutler: I think I know which one you mean, there is a side-bar version of that same advertisement I think.

Comment: @Surfbutler: yeah, that one is just there for completeness sake. It'd take me *quite some time* to reduce my reputation to below 200 with that route..

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know the sidebars had the same ads, cool.

Comment: Just made my question into a feature request, if that's ok with you?

Comment: @Surfbutler sure; I'll try and update my answer later on.

Comment: Or, in your case, approximately 574 big bounties.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: that'll take a little over a year, as you are limited to [3 concurrent bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813), and you cannot award a bounty before it has been active for at least 2 days. By that time [I'll have gained another 125k or so](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2013-01-01).

Comment: You'd better get started then!!  If you need any help picking out candidates, just holler!  And in the end you'll have the sweet success of re-enabled ads.

Comment: Also, if this "I want a low reputation" idea catches on, then dumping your reputation on other people would be rather antisocial.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Hey, if you're ever out of people to give rep to, there's always your friendly neighborhood shiny metallic object! ;)

Comment: i would love this, with default as is now, but ability to get back ads.