# Why is there a "reduce ads" privileges since ads is the source of income?

Tags: discussion, privileges, advertising

At 200 reputation points, users receive "reduce ads" privilege.

Why does Stack Overflow give users this privilege since "reduce ads" means "reduce income"?

Comment: Ads are not their source of income, the careers site is.

Comment: Ads may not be their *primary* source of income, but it is still a source.

Comment: Related feature request: [Re-enable adverts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271707/247702)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

People that contribute are *important*, because it is the contributions that attract the traffic in the first place. As a thank-you for those contributions you don't get served as many in-your-face  advertisements. Stack Overflow wouldn't be able to sell advertising if there was no user-contributed content!

The advertisements are aimed at the masses. Consistent contributors are not the masses.

Note that advertisements are not the *only* source of income. They are not even the main source. There are also [tag sponsorships](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251363/how-can-i-set-an-icon-on-a-tag) (those little icons on tags are paid for by sponsors), and the Careers 2.0 site. Take a look at the [Stack Exchange Team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) page and compare the number of Careers staff vs. advertising staff and draw your own conclusions as to where the money comes from.

Also see [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)

That said, if you want to continue support Stack Overflow, you can now *re-enable* the extra ads in your profile. See [Choose to see reduced ads or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not/275687#275687).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for tag icons. I find them really annoying (they draw the eyes to names that, statistically, are always unimportant in my case) but if they are useful for funding, I will just keep putting any tag with an icon in my “ignored tags” list.